# Disabled form checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I want disabled all inputs in form checkout in Magento 2.
[image]

In the photo it looks like I want it to be seen, but I do not know in which Magento file you have to modify that.

I do photo only one input, but I want all form disabled, because only can buy if is logged and I don't want that the data can be changed.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Do you want to disable to whole checkout or only state and zip code fields?

Comment: I want disabled all form. Data will be charged from other site and only can be modified in the other site. The changes are in the other site